# What is Captain Kirk's secret pain?

Tags: star-trek, captain-kirk, the-final-frontier

In ***Star Trek V: The Final Frontier***, Spock's half-brother Sybok exposes the "secret pain" of people he encounters.

Sybok forces McCoy to reveal that he had hastened his own dying father's death, only to learn of a cure shortly after.  Spock's secret pain is rooted in Sarek's displeasure with Spock's humanity.

Kirk, however, does not permit his pain to be exposed.

[image]

**What is Kirk's secret pain?**

Any relevant details from script notes and drafts of screenplays, novelizations, and interviews would be most appreciated.

(I tried to ask William Shatner this at the [Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/08/coverage-of-star-trek-50th-anniversary-celebration-for-sffse/), but the queue was just too long....)

Comment: Saw the title, assumed "pain" was a typo for "plan" :-P

Comment: Does it really matter? Damn it, Praxis, you're a Stack Exchange user. You know that pain and guilt can't be taken away with a wave of a magic wand. They're the things Kirk carries with him, the things that make him who he is. If he loses them, he loses himself. Kirk doesn't want his pain taken away! He needs his pain!

Comment: It was that he not only had to watch this movie when it we completed, but that he knew he'd have to bear most of the blame for it...

Comment: Kirk was haunted by not getting the green woman's communicator number the morning after they made their interstellar love connection.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The relevant bit from the film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier_(novel)) is slightly different from the wording in the film. There's also some internal dialogue from Kirk himself.

> *The very thought made images shimmer and swirl in the shadows:
>   **Enterprise, as her fiery hull streaked through the sky toward Genesis
>   like a falling star as she plummeted to her death. David, my son, my
>   own flesh and blood, dead before I had the chance to really know
>   him. Lost chances with his mother, Carol...***
>
> *"I don't need Sybok to take me on a tour of them." "Jim," McCoy
>   pleaded, his eyes dulled by euphoria, "if you'd just unbend and allow
>   yourself'*
>
> *"To be brainwashed by this con man? You said it yourself, Doctor,
>   remember?" "I was wrong," McCoy countered. "This "con man' took away my pain! No psychiatrist in the universe has ever..."*
>
> *"Dammit, Bones, you're a doctor. You know that pain and guilt can't be
>   dispelled with the wave of a magic wand. They're things we carry with
>   us - the things that make us who we are. If we lose them, we lose
>   ourselves. **I don't want my pain taken away. I don't want to forget
>   David and Carol and losing the Enterprise. I need my pain."***

Comment: Well, that's disappointingly obvious. I was hoping for something juicier. Nonetheless, +1 for helping to make a little more sense of this dreadful movie.

Comment: Hmm, so are they screwing up every other movie again?  I thought this one was suppose to be the "good" one.

Comment: @Nelson This seems to require a TBBT quote. Raj Koothrappali: "Are you joking? Star Trek V is the standard against which all badness is measured!"

Comment: @RogueJedi - I don't think anyone has ever accused this novel of being well-written.

Comment: What's that random asterisk at the end of the third paragraph? Also, is the paragraph arrangement that way in the book? New speakers are usually supposed to start a new paragraph...

Comment: @jpmc26 - The asterisk was a rogue editing mark. The layout is much the same as can be found in my ebook version. You'd have to look at the paper version to find out if it's the same.

Comment: @RogueJedi, *as she plummeted to her death* is not part of the metaphor (simile), it is merely descriptive. It could have been *Enterprise, as she plummeted to her death, as her fiery hull streaked through the sky toward Genesis like a falling star*... though I do agree it is bad writing.     And it's imagery, not a full sentence which adds to the grammatical confusion.

Comment: @Valorum : The truly shocking thing is that Dillard's novelizations are actually not the worst (the Vonda McIntyre ones come to mind).

Comment: @Praxis - I feel like Vonda McIntyre's novelisations are best when she's got the finalised screenplay to work with, rather than trying to work off early drafts.

Comment: Where do the official novelisations stand in terms of canon?  Are they part of it, or as close as one can get without being part of it?

Comment: @Tango - Canon in the trek universe is basically user-chooser. The books are fully authorised which, theoretically, puts them on the same level as the technical manuals and writer's guides. I always operate on the principle that an official novelisation is *canon unless contradicted by a higher source*.

Comment: If the events of ST:WOK won't suffice for Kirk's secret pain, what about the loss of his family members in TOS:"Operation: Annihilate!"?